# Two UIWebView with different login

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, uiwebview

I'm building iOS application that load 2 `UIWebView` and in each of them need to be a different login to google.

The problem is that when i login to the first one, the second `UIWebView` is using the same login.

There is any option to separate between their cookies?

Comment: UIWebViews always shared same cookies.. you can explore WKWebview

Comment: Dear @ShauketSheikh , i checked with WKWebView but unfortunately they this class not support `didReceiveResponse` like `WebView`